# Function to count if X amount amount of days as a full month

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

We offer services for clients and each client has an Authorization for 90 days
I want to create a function which counts 15 days as full months.
For example, let’s say a client get Authorization on 10/17/2017. It’s means it’s less than 15 days for October so that Authorization will not count for October, but it has to count for November, December and January 2018.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    select 
        d.ClientId,
        LOC
        datediff(day, l.DecisionOn, d.duedate) 'Days',
        l.DecisionOn,
        d.duedate
    from code d
        join codeloc l on d.curdocversionid = l.docversionid
        join codeaccess a on a.docversionid = d.curdocversionid
    where codeid = 69999
            and aoca in ('68','69','70','71','72','74')
),
T AS (
SELECT ClientId, LOC, COUNT(*) CNT FROM CTE
WHERE [Days] > 15
    AND AuthorizedDecisionOn > DATEADD(MONTH, (CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) , CAST( GETDATE() as date)) 
    AND duedate < DATEADD(MONTH,3 + (CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) , CAST( GETDATE() as date))
GROUP BY ClientId, LOC
)
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query? can you add some sample data from your tables?

Comment: they want be able to see how many current clients are authorized at any given time that count toward our target

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database. Table schemas, sample data and expected results are quite helpful.

Comment: Tip: `GetDate()` is treated a bit oddly in queries. Each _instance_ will have a constant value within a query. For example `select GetDate() as D1, GetDate() as D2 from SomeTable` may return two different values for the two columns, but they will not vary from one row to the next. When using `GetDate()` in multiple statements, e.g. within a stored procedure, one may avoid interesting surprises by getting a single value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and use `@Now` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an inline table valued function (iTvf) that will give you what you need.
(note: I use iTvf's because they outperform scalar udfs)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.monthsBetweenMinDay
(
  @fromDate date,
  @toDate   date,
  @minDays  tinyint
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT Months = m.mb + 
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,d.fd,dateadd(month, -m.mb, d.td)) >= @minDays THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM (VALUES (@fromDate, @toDate)) d(fd,td) -- from date and todate
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
  CASE WHEN d.fd > d.td THEN NULL
       WHEN DATEPART(day, d.fd) > DATEPART(day, d.td) THEN DATEDIFF(month, d.fd, d.td)-1
       ELSE DATEDIFF(month, d.fd, d.td) END)) m(mb);
```

Here's an example of the function in action:

```
-- sample data
CREATE TABLE #dates (date1 date, date2 date);

INSERT #dates
SELECT dt.dt, CAST(DATEADD(day, [days].d, DATEADD(month, months.m, dt.dt)) as date)
FROM (VALUES ('20170101')) dt(dt), (VALUES (4),(15),(25)) [days](d), (VALUES(0),(1),(4)) months(m);

-- solution
SELECT * 
FROM #dates d
CROSS APPLY dbo.monthsBetweenMinDay(d.date1, d.date2, 15);
```

**Results**

```
date1       date2       Months
----------  ----------  -----------
2017-01-01  2017-01-05  0
2017-01-01  2017-01-16  1
2017-01-01  2017-01-26  1
2017-01-01  2017-02-05  1
2017-01-01  2017-02-16  2
2017-01-01  2017-02-26  2
2017-01-01  2017-05-05  4
2017-01-01  2017-05-16  5
2017-01-01  2017-05-26  5
```

Comment: this is ok when trying to do it for a month. I want it in days between month. For example. 8/28/2017
and
10/16/2017

Comment: this is ok when trying to do it for a month. I want it in days between month. For example. 8/28/2017
and
10/16/2017

Clientid, Year, Month, Count, countstowardstarget if (count > 15)
2, 2017, 8, 4, 0 
2, 2017, 9, 30, 1
2, 2017, 10, 16, 1

group by clientid, year, month.
 The reason why month 8 count is 0 is that the client received a service on 08/28/2017 when it was 4 days for the month to be over. so it will not count.